# How to set style for "body" of a component in angular?

Tags: angular, sass

I found a [codepen](https://codepen.io/frytyler/pen/EGdtg), it is a login page. I want to put it in my angular app but I can't set the style for the background. My background is empty.

Here's what I put in my angular app:
1. the html file

```
<div class="login">
  <h1>Login</h1>
  <form method="post">
    <input type="text" name="u" placeholder="Username" required="required"/>
    <input type="password" name="p" placeholder="Password" required="required"/>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-block btn-large">Let me in.</button>
  </form>
</div>
```

Then I put the corresponding css file in the codepen to my .scss file in my angular app.

You can look inside the codepen for more code, I just did a copy paste to my angular app, and following is my .ts file (for the component):

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-login',
  templateUrl: './login.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./login.component.scss']
})
export class LoginComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

So, my question is: how to set the style for the "body" of an angular component ? (I want to use this component as a whole page)

Answer (score 1):

From [Documentation](https://angular.io/guide/component-styles#host):

> You can use the `:host` pseudo-class selector to target styles in the
>   **element that hosts the component** (as opposed to targeting elements inside the component's template).

So in your `login.component.scss` file:

```
:host{
  background-color: cyan;
}
```

If you really want to add css to the body of your app, you can do it in the `styles.css` file at the root of your project.

Answer (score 0):

you can put the CSS in the corresponding login.component.scss file.

Comment: That is exactly what I did.

Comment: can you try putting simple CSS property in ./login.component.scss file and see if its getting reflected? Just first step to verify if your stylesheet is being read.

Comment: I am sure that the .scss stylesheet file is being read because my submit button has style.

Comment: cool! means just CSS needs to be read properly. You can try the suggestion by Maarti or just make sure whatever CSS you have is appropriate for your corresponding SCSS. Also, you can try pulling common styles like @import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans); in your global styles.css file

Answer (score 0):

In your css file use :host

```
:host {
    background-color: red;
    display: block;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have a `styles.css` or `styles.scss` stylesheet in the root of your application, you can add a style for the body in there like this:

```
body {
    background-color: black;
}
```

This will change the background color for the entire application, however. If you only want to change the background color of the login component, add a `background-color` style to the *login.component.scss* stylesheet.

Comment: I just want the background style to affect my login page, then I tried to put "background-color: yellow" at the top level of my "login.component.scss" file, then webstorm is not happy about this.

Comment: Does it log an error in the console? Try ".login { background-color: yellow; }".

Comment: No error from console, and the ".login { background-color: yellow; }" does work, but it only works for the small area around the login area, not the whole page.

Comment: Awesome! So now you need to add more styling to the ".login {}" class in your stylesheet to make the login component take up the entire height of the page. The div element only takes up enough height to show whatever is nested within it, so that's why it doesn't take up the entire page.